# Android + LibVLC - request X not implemented + can't get Subtitles Surface - How to fix these?

Tags: android, libvlc

Warning, android newbie developer here... So my terminology may be a little off ;)

I have a small application I wrote for android that uses LibVLC (latest, 3.0.XX).

When ever I initialize my video player, I get the following:

```
10-22 04:20:03.365 22293 22601 E VLC     : [d27d4630/5849] libvlc window: request 1 not implemented
10-22 04:20:03.366 22293 22601 E VLC     : [d2855430/5849] libvlc vout display: can't get Subtitles Surface
10-22 04:20:03.371 22293 22601 E VLC     : [d27d4630/5849] libvlc window: request 0 not implemented
10-22 04:20:03.371 22293 22601 E VLC     : [d27d4630/5849] libvlc window: request 0 not implemented
10-22 04:20:03.371 22293 22601 E VLC     : [d27d4630/5849] libvlc window: request 1 not implemented
```

By initialize I mean load new media via `setMedia(...)`. Although it could be happening at the `play()` function.

These seam fairly harmless as everything is working just fine, but if possible I would like to disable whatever libvlc is trying to do that causes them to pop up.

A) The window request ones appear to be related to mouse related events that android does not support, and thus they fail. I tried passing `--no-mouse` as an option to libvlc, but no dice... It did not help.

B) The vout display appears to be related to where subtitles should be shown. I do not use them, nor will I ever, so I tried passing a few various options to my libvlc init to disable subtitles all together but none of it helped.

Any ideas how to clean up the libvlc / mediaplayer / vout / media init up so these don't pollute my logs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A) The window request ones appear to be related to mouse related events that android does not support, and thus they fail. I tried passing --no-mouse as an option to libvlc, but no dice... It did not help.

Besides disabling the logs, I'm afraid you can't suppress those.

```
static int Control(vout_window_t *wnd, int cmd, va_list ap)
{
    (void) ap;
    msg_Err (wnd, "request %d not implemented", cmd);
    return VLC_EGENERIC;
}
```

> B) The vout display appears to be related to where subtitles should be shown. I do not use them, nor will I ever, so I tried passing a few various options to my libvlc init to disable subtitles all together but none of it helped.

You didn't share how you implemented your surfaces/awindow/videoviews, but provide a surface for subs, even if you don't plan on using them. That'd make the log go away.

```
if (AndroidWindow_ConnectSurface(sys, p_window) != 0)
{
    if (id == AWindow_Video)
        msg_Err(vd, "can't get Video Surface");
    else if (id == AWindow_Subtitles)
        msg_Err(vd, "can't get Subtitles Surface");
    goto error;
}
```

https://github.com/videolan/vlc-3.0/blob/738da6c2737d2da93b24b7cce47944d45d10d8d3/modules/video_output/android/display.c#L402